# Simple ATM Algorithm

Tags: c#

I have a simple ATM algorithm that, given an amount to take, should deliver the minimum amount of 100 bills, 50 bills, and 20 bills.

```
var amount = 280;
var availableBiils = new[] { 100, 50, 20 };
var usedNumberOfBills = new[] { 0, 0, 0 };

for (var i = 0; i < availableBiils.Count(); i++)
{
    var bill = availableBiils[i];
    while (amount >= bill)
    {
        amount = amount - bill;

        usedNumberOfBills[i] += 1;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < usedNumberOfBills.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{availableBiils[i]}    {usedNumberOfBills[i]}");
}
```

My approach does not work for some cases, for example 280, 260, 240, and so on.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger? This is a simple problem and it'd be an ideal example to get familiar with the debugger - you could set breakpoints and inspect values during the loop and see where things are different from what you expect.

Comment: Seems sort of odd that you don't have 10 bills. Without those you won't be able to compute some values because you always check for 50's first before 20's.

Comment: Works for me: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/RecentAstonishingMultitasking#main.cs.  FWIW, there's no `Count()` member on `int[]`, so your posted code won't compile.

Comment: That depends on whether or not it has `using System.Linq;`. Arrays implement `ICollection<T>` so the `Count()` extension method *can* be used, even if it's a little daft to do so. We don't see the `using`s, though, as this is not even a complete method definition, let alone a whole file. For `ICollection<T>`, it will defer to the `Count` property, which will in turn access `Length` on the array, but using `Count()` this will prevent the compiler's optimization ability when it sees `Length` used.

Comment: @gunr2171 Likely that is the cause. it tries to fill the amount using bills that will not enable getting the amount (with 50 and 20 you cannot get to 80)

Comment: Note that the OP's specification doesn't stipulate that the total amount of currency match *exactly,* only that the correct number of each denomination is calculated.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, but I need to start o analyze to the highest ones.

Comment: After you are done with the 100 bills you should check if using a 50 bill would leave you an amount that can be fullfilled using 20 bills, if not you should not use the 50 bill and use only 20 bills instead

Comment: If you need an exact solution, you'll need some sort of backtracking algorithm so that, if a particular denomination fails, you can try again with smaller bills (sort of a "Tower of Hanoi" problem).

Comment: Or just fill it with 20's, and then replace each group of five 20's with two 50's, etc.

Comment: Too bad I saw this late. Given the scenario you provided, I've given you a simple answer. But this answer won't work for all situations but as for the scenario you provided, it does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working sample I just created for you.

This is the struct that handles the whole transaction:

```
struct AmountManager
{
    private int amount = 0;
    private List<int> specialAmount = new List<int> { 80, 60 };

    public AmountManager(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    List<int> Notes = new List<int> { 100, 50, 20 };

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks how many 100 notes can be used given the amount.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>taple representing the number of 100 notes to be used, and the remaining amount</returns>
    public (int Quotient, int Remainder) HundredsUsed() 
        => Math.DivRem(amount, Notes[0]);


    /// <summary>
    /// Checks how many 50 notes can be used given the remaining amount from the HundredsUsed().
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>taple representing the number of 50 notes to be used, and the remaining amount</returns>
    public (int Quotient, int Remainder) FiftiesUsed()
    {
        if (HundredsUsed().Remainder == 0) 
            return (0, 0);

        if (specialAmount.Contains(HundredsUsed().Remainder))
            return (0, HundredsUsed().Remainder);
        else
            return Math.DivRem(HundredsUsed().Remainder, Notes[1]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks how many 20 notes can be used given the remaining amount from the FiftiesUsed().
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>taple representing the number of 20 notes to be used, and the remaining amount</returns>
    public (int Quotient, int Remainder) TwentiesUsed()
        => (FiftiesUsed().Remainder < Notes[2]) ? (0, 0) :  Math.DivRem(FiftiesUsed().Remainder, Notes[2]);

    public string Print()
        => $@"{Notes[0]}({HundredsUsed().Quotient}), {Notes[1]}({FiftiesUsed().Quotient}), {Notes[2]}({TwentiesUsed().Quotient})";
}
```

Create a console application, and create an instance of this struct:
`AmountManager transact = new AmountManager(YourNumber)`
and then run the print method `transact.Print()`;

I have tested it with the following values:

- `220` - returns `100(2), 50(0), 20(1)`
- `260` - returns `100(2), 50(0), 20(3)`
- `270` - returns `100(2), 50(1), 20(1)`
- `290` - returns `100(2), 50(2), 20(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your unique problem is when you have 60 or 80. In these cases you take 50 and remain 10 or 30 that you can't solve. Simply check this cases.

```
var amount = 280;
var availableBiils = new[] { 100, 50, 20 };
var usedNumberOfBills = new[] { 0, 0, 0 };

for (var i = 0; i < availableBiils.Count(); i++)
{
    var bill = availableBiils[i];
    while (amount >= bill)
    {
        if (amount == 60)
        {
            amount = 0;
            usedNumberOfBills[2] += 3;
        }
        else if (amount == 80)
        {
            amount = 0;
            usedNumberOfBills[2] += 4;
        }
        else
        {
            amount = amount - bill;
            usedNumberOfBills[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < usedNumberOfBills.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{availableBiils[i]}    {usedNumberOfBills[i]}");
}
```

If your available bills are well known, you may also do this:

```
var amount = 280;
var availableBiils = new[] { 100, 50, 20 };
var usedNumberOfBills = new[] { 0, 0, 0 };
            
usedNumberOfBills[0] = Math.DivRem(amount, 100, out int pending);

if (pending != 60 && pending != 80)
{
    usedNumberOfBills[1] = Math.DivRem(pending, 50, out amount);
    usedNumberOfBills[2] = amount / 20;
}
else
{
    usedNumberOfBills[2] = pending / 20;
}

for (var i = 0; i < usedNumberOfBills.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{availableBiils[i]}    {usedNumberOfBills[i]}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm will work for every amount only, if for each bill (excluding lowest) you have at least one bill, that divided gives whole number. For 50 only lower bill is 20, but 50/20=2.5, so it isn't whole number.

Simplest solution is to add 10 bill.